# flash game development AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am developing a game in flash AS3 in which multiple items are falling down and have to be caught it at the bottom using the mouse.

just want to brief you regarding the game.

This is the link for similar game  : http://www.playitontheweb.com/games/Catch-Falling-Fruit-game.htm

```
At frame 1 > Preloader
At frame 2 > Game front page.
At frame 3 > Game introduction.
At frame 4 > user will b playing the game.
At frame 5 > Final Score.
```

This is what i want to make it in functionality wise.

Here is the script script(AS3) which plays the game in all frames. From 1 to 5 which i dont want: Please help......

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class CatchingGame extends MovieClip {
    var catcher:Catcher;
    var nextObject:Timer;
    var objects:Array = new Array();
    var score:int = 0;
    const speed:Number = 7.0;

    public function CatchingGame() {
        catcher = new Catcher();
        catcher.y = 350;
        addChild(catcher);
        setNextObject();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);
    }

    public function setNextObject() {
        nextObject = new Timer(1000+Math.random()*1000,1);
        nextObject.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newObject);
        nextObject.start();
    }

    public function newObject(e:Event) {
        var goodObjects:Array = ["Circle1","Circle2"];
        var badObjects:Array = ["Square1","Square2"];
        if (Math.random() < .5) {
            var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*goodObjects.length);
            var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(goodObjects[r]) as Class;
            var newObject:MovieClip = new classRef(); 
            newObject.typestr = "good";
        } else {
            r = Math.floor(Math.random()*badObjects.length);
            classRef = getDefinitionByName(badObjects[r]) as Class;
            newObject = new classRef(); 
            newObject.typestr = "bad";
        }
        newObject.x = Math.random()*500;
        addChild(newObject);
        objects.push(newObject);
        setNextObject();
    }

    public function moveObjects(e:Event) {
        for(var i:int=objects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            objects[i].y += speed;
            if (objects[i].y > 400) {
                removeChild(objects[i]);
                objects.splice(i,1);
            }
            if (objects[i].hitTestObject(catcher)) {
                if (objects[i].typestr == "good") {
                    score += 5;
                } else {
                    score -= 1;
                }
                if (score < 0) score = 0;
                scoreDisplay.text = "Score: "+score;
                removeChild(objects[i]);
                objects.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        catcher.x = mouseX;

    }
}
}
```

Also would like to ask you can we add a timer in that of 60 sec?
as soon as the timer gets over it goes to the last frame to shaw the final score.

Answer (score 0):

- call `stop()` to stay within current frame, call nextFrame() to advance to next scene
- global function `getTimer()` gives you number of milliseconds passed from swf launch, you can measure time with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use gotoAndStop() to go to the frame you want and stop there. I would recommend that command over stop() simply because it bundles both the frame changing and stop behaviors into one; otherwise they are the same thing.